# Use content from the field of one collection as a determinant in which collection the data will be fetched

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swift5

First, I'll explain briefly explain what I'm trying to do. In Firestore, I have a collection `specialities`, where I store different specialities names in different document:

example:

```
        DOCUMENT         FIELD/CONTENT
                 
        type_0           spty : "Cardiologist"
        type_1           spty : "Oftalmologist"
```

Then, I have other collections, each one with a speciality as collection's name. Inside each speciality collection, I have:

example:

```
     COLLECTION: CARDIOLOGIST
                DOCUMENT          FIELD/CONTENT

                  type_0          name: "John" | spty: "Cardiologist"
                  type_1          name: "James" | spty: "Cardiologist


  
    COLLECTION: OFTALMOLOGIST
                DOCUMENT          FIELD/CONTENT

                  type_0          name: "Wilson" | spty: "Oftalmologist"
                  type_1          name: "David" | spty: "Oftalmologist"
```

What I'm trying to do is: If the user clicks on the text "Cardiologist", he will get the names "John" and "James". But, if it clicks on the text "Oftalmologist", he will get the names "Wilson" and "David"

Taking about the code, I have:

```
struct Spty: Identifiable, Codable{
 @DocumentID var id: String?
 var spty: String
 var r: Int
 var g: Int
 var b: Int
}


class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
  @Published var specialities = [Spty]()
  @Published var search = ""

   func fetchData(){
    Firestore.firestore().collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot else {return }
        self.specialities = documents.documents.compactMap { (doc) -> Spty? in
         return try?  doc.data(as: Spty.self)
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

And then, where the question is all about:

```
struct Details: Identifiable, Codable{
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var name: String
  var spty: String
}

  class DetailsViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
    @Published var details = [Details]()

    func getDetails(){
    Firestore.firestore().collection(?????).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, Error) in
     guard let documents = querySnapshot else {return}
    self.details = documents.documents.compactMap{ (doc) -> Details? in
        return try? doc.data(as: Details.self)
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

To succeed in what I want to do, I need to ,in collection(), find a way to refer to the content of field "spty" from collection "specialities"

After lots of researches and tests, I haven't found a way to do it. I'd like to know if its possible. If so, how to do it and, if not, what other way I could do it.

Comment: You need two queries, one to get the chosen specialty, then another to get the names.  You can't do it with one query - Firestore does not have a way to join the contents of multiple collections with a single query.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for replying. Do you have any links where there's a similiar example?

Comment: Performing two queries is not really any more complex than performing one query, so I would not expect there to be a dedicated example.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fetched the list of specialities from the collection `specialities`, it's just string data in your app.  Use it like you would use any other string data.  The argument to .collection() is *JUST* a string - no more - so you can use a literal `"specialities"` as you do in the first example, or a variable that holds a string.  How you store the result of the first fetch, and how you associate it with the "buttons" you don't show here, but it really is a simple as that.  How to do all *that* has nothing to do with Firestore, so you'll have to go elsewhere for that.

Comment: thank you for replying. I didn't understand  the part `How you store the result of the first fetch, and how you associate it with the "buttons" you don't show here`. Isn't `associate it with the "buttons"` what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Really, you need to go back to the very basics of programming in swift - which I am not familiar with.  Judging by what you're showing here, you have cut-and-pasted some code you don't understand *at all*